# Powershell and overriden comparision operators

Tags: .net, powershell, sdk

How can one create an object that when its operators, such as:

```
operator > (Object obj1, Object obj2)  
operator < (Object obj1, Object obj2)
```

, are overridden PowerShell utilizes these operators?

Such that:

```
where-object { $CustomObject -gt 12 }
```

would call:

```
public static bool operator > (Object object1, Object object2)
```

Is it possible?

To clarify:

- The object exists within a .NET assembly
- The object has overridden comparision operators
- PowerShell does not seem to honor these operators

Comment: Can you give more of a hint as to what you are trying to do? Perhaps its possible another way.

Comment: are you looking to do this strictly in Powershell, or create a .NET object that has the overridden operators that can be used in Powershell?

Comment: Sorry that a really vague question. I'm trying to create a .NET object and the compare it inside PowerShell

Comment: Good point, if the object is a custom object created in .NET you can do the operator overloading there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe you can do operator overloading in Powershell.

Comment: Yeah I'm seeing the same thing. It would be cool if I could utilize overridden comparison operator :\

Comment: If he is attempting to "create a .NET object" (presumably in C# or VB) why would he need to override operators in PowerShell when it can be done easily in C# or VB?

Comment: You can (now, years later) do operator overloading in PowerShell classes - https://gist.github.com/JFFail/c629e8a667bed62f3eb980e902491841 - even if it's not relevant to this question, this was a high google result saying you can't do it, so here's a comment saying you can.

Answer (score 14):

PowerShell is using the IComparable interface to compare objects. At least, this is what the following little experiment shows:

```
$src = @'
using System;
namespace Acme 
{
    public class Foo : IComparable
    {
        public Foo(int value)
        {
            this.Value = value;
        }

        public int Value { get; private set; }

        public static bool operator >(Foo foo1, Foo foo2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In operator >");
            return (foo1.Value > foo2.Value);
        }

        public static bool operator <(Foo foo1, Foo foo2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In operator <");
            return (foo1.Value < foo2.Value);
        }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In CompareTo");
            if (obj == null) return 1;

            Foo foo2 = obj as Foo;
            if (foo2 == null) throw new ArgumentException("Not type Foo","obj");

            if (this.Value == foo2.Value)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if (this.Value > foo2.Value)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else 
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
'@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $src -Language CSharpVersion3

$foo1 = new-object Acme.Foo 4
$foo2 = new-object Acme.Foo 8

$foo1 -gt $foo2
In CompareTo
False
```

Comment: For those in a hurry, you can overload `.CompareTo(object)` and possibly `.Equals(object)` to enable a `-eq -gt -lt` comparison for your custom class.  NOTE that you can't explicitly type the input variable in the parameter declaration (this will NOT work: `int CompareTo([MyClass] $obj)` but this will: `int CompareTo($obj)` )

Comment: And [it turns out](https://gist.github.com/JFFail/c629e8a667bed62f3eb980e902491841) you can overload Assignment operators also like `=, +, -, *, /`  (Thanks to JFFail for posting that)

Answer (score 3):

You can overload an operator in C#

If you are using the operator in powershell, the c# overloaded operator will be used

```
        // overloading + operator
        public static Nimber operator +(Nimber left, Nimber right)
    {
        var length = (left.List.Count > right.List.Count) ? left.List.Count : right.List.Count;
        var list = new int[length];

        for (int i = 0; i < left.List.Count; i++)
        {
            list[i] = left.List[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < right.List.Count; i++)
        {
            list[i] += right.List[i];
        }

        return new Nimber(list);
    }
```

posershell use

```
Add-Type -Path $TheAssemblyPath
$n1 = New-Object nim.nimber (1,2,4) 
$n2 = New-Object nim.nimber (10,20,40,50) 
"n1=$n1 and n2=$n2"

$n3 = $n1 + $n2
"n3=$n3"
```

and the output is

```
n1=1, 2, 4 and n2=10, 20, 40, 50
n3=11, 22, 44, 50
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to compare two instances of a custom PowerShell class with the `-lt`, `-le`, `-ge` and `-gt` operators, your class should implement the `System.IComparable` interface, and you can do that in a plain PowerShell (that is, you don't need to use `AddType`):

```
Class MyClass : System.IComparable
{
    [int] $Value
    MyClass([int] $v)
    {
        $this.Value = $v
    }
    [int] CompareTo($that)
    {
        return $this.Value - $that.Value
    }
}

$instance1 = [MyClass]::new(1)
$instance2 = [MyClass]::new(2)

Write-Output ($instance1 -lt $instance2)
#Output: True
Write-Output ($instance1 -le $instance2)
#Output: True
Write-Output ($instance1 -ge $instance2)
#Output: False
Write-Output ($instance1 -gt $instance2)
#Output: False
```

BTW I faced problems when comparing subclasses: see [PowerShell IComparable with subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203695/powershell-icomparable-with-subclasses)

Comment: This is technically a duplicate of Keith's answer below but I found this one easier to scan quickly to find what I need so I upvoted

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do operator overloading in PowerShell, but I believe the way you've declared it will work as PowerShell should obey the operator overloading of .NET.  When this does not work what you are often seeing is different objects on each side, i.e. a [int] -gt [string].  You can always try explictly casting both of the objects before a comparison.

Hope this helps