# Can powershell call subclasses from external C# dll

Tags: powershell, dll, subclass

I have some simple code from:
https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/dllsandexecutables/article.php/c4239/Creating-and-Using-C-DLLs.htm

which generates a dll to do some simple math.  I wanted to add a subclass

```
namespace MathFunctions
{
    public class Add : MultiClass
    {
        public static int MultiplyAndAdd(int a, int b, int c)
        {
            return (a * b) + c;
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it from powershell.

Running powershell against the master classes returns data back without an issue

```
Import-module("C:\temp\MathFunctions.dll")
[MathFunctions.MultiClass]::Multiply(10, 2)
```

returns 20 as expected, but I can't figure the format to access the subclass.  I've tried variations on:

```
[MathFunctions.MultiClass.Add]::MultiplyAndAdd(10, 2, 3)
[MathFunctions.MultiClass+Add]::MultiplyAndAdd(10, 2, 3)
[MathFunctions.MultiClass]:Add:MultiplyAndAdd(10, 2, 3)
[MathFunctions.MultiClass]::Add.MultiplyAndAdd(10, 2, 3)
```

but I always get variations on

```
Unable to find type [MathFunctions.MultiClass.Add]
```

I've also looked for the method in powershell via:

```
[MathFunctions.MultiClass] | get-member  -MemberType method
```

but my subclass isn't listed.

I know I'm accessing it incorrectly.  I can't figure out how to access the subclass from powershell.

I'm fairly sure subclasses can be accessed, as the closest example is:
[PowerShell IComparable with subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203695/powershell-icomparable-with-subclasses)
but I don't see how he aliased it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you bluuf who pointed me in the right direction.

I ended up using dotPeek to take the dll apart (now it was public [blush]).

Code is as above and the powershell method is just the subclass name:

```
[MathFunctions.Add]::MultiplyAndAdd(5,2,3)
```

which gave an answer - not an error

Comment: If you think you've answered your own question in a manner that will benefit future readers, I encourage you to [self-accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). That said, my (biased) view is that my answer does a better job of explaining the misconception that prompted your question.

Answer (score 0):

To explain the confusion in more detail:

**You mistakenly thought that class-inheritance relationships must be reflected in a given class' full (namespace-qualified) type name**, so you thought that because class `Add` *derives from* class `MultiClass`, `MultiClass` too must be reflected in the full type name.

In reality, **a class' derivation is irrelevant with respect to its full name**; all that matter is the *namespace* in which it is placed.
In other words: **to form the full type name for any type (class), use 
`<EnclosingNamespace>.<TypeName>`**<sup>[1]</sup>, which in your case means:

```
 MathFunctions.Add
```

Using that as a PowerShell type literal - `[MathFunctions.Add]` - allows you to access the static `MultiplyAndAdd()` method via `::`, the static-member access operator, as shown in your own answer.

---

Also, remember that ***tab-completion* can be helpful** here, because it works with type names too; in your case, typing `[Add<tab>` will expand to `[MathFunctions.Add`, yielding the full type name.
(If multiple available (public) type names start with `Add`, you may to have to press the tab key repeatedly to cycle through the matches.)

---

<sup>[1] A variation is required to access a [*nested* class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types), i.e., a class embedded in another class:

`<EnclosingNamespace>.<EnclosingTypeName>+<NestedTypeName>`, e.g., if your `Add` class had a nested class named `Inner`: 
`MathFunctions.Add+Inner`</sup>